# Display the ID value in workflow

Tags: workflow

Hi I have one requirement where object 'A' has a lookup of account. I have one more  field which should display the owner of account whose lookup I have given. Owner field in account also has a lookup to user.
I wrote a workflow to get owner of account field but it displays the owner id i want name to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering following API names for the fields you've mentioned-

- Account - AccountId
- OwnerID - Owner__c

*Use like that *AccountId.Owner__r.name*